# Determine if file write out is true c

Tags: c, file-io

Is there a way to find out if a file write occurred in c. I'm supposed to return a 0 if I wrote to the file and -1 if nothing was written.

Comment: most write operations have some kind of return value which will indicate success or failure.

Comment: Functions in the `*printf` family return the number of characters they wrote on success. So you could test for a return value of > 0. Whenever you need information like this, it is easier to go to the function's man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf

Comment: I hadn't tried anything, it was more of a generalized question. I wasn't sure what to search for so I thought that I would ask you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `fwrite()`, for example, the return code is the number of items written.

Similarly, `fprintf()` returns the number of characters written.

So you can examine the return code to figure out if anything was written, something like:

```
if (fprintf (fh, "val=%d\n", value) == 0)
    return -1;
return 0;
```

or:

```
if (fwrite (buffer, sizeof(something), 7, fh) == 0)
    return -1;
return 0;
```

Keep in mind you're asking for a nothing/something indication and the something means partial or complete success. If you want to know *how much* of what you requested was written, hat's a tiny bit more complex.